# Add OpenId bug with SE OpenID

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, openid

I tried to add the SE OpenId to all my profiles, and was surprised that on Area51 the login did not work.

I clicked 'add openid'.
I clicked 'login with stackexchange'

[image: Error message]

I've repeated this three times today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Area 51's OpenId-handling logic was a bit out of sync with the rest of the network. It's fixed now. Thanks.